# Should `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` be called every time after `glBindBuffer` without VAO?

Tags: opengl

I can only use the standard interface specified in OpenGL ES 2.0. For the  platform limits I can't use the VAO in the glext.

What I want to ask:

1. Does `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` effect only the current bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` or globally?
2. If they only effect the current bound one do I need call them every time after after `glBindBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` modify the global state or the state of a VAO if one is present. Thus you will have to call these functions whenever you want do draw a buffer.